# How do I run a php script on Angular on input change?

Tags: php, sql, angular, crud

It seems that I am having trouble running an SQL query on the server via PHP on Input change. Could someone please take a look on my code and assist me?

The service that is responsible for handling the http request to the server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {
  public url = 'http://localhost/web_api/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerNormal(data)
  {
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'registerNormal.php', data);
  }

  accountExists(data)
  {
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'existingAccounts.php', data);
  }
}
```

The function responsible for passing the data

```
  CheckAccountAvailability(values)
  {
    const registerNormalFormData = new FormData();
    registerNormalFormData.append('username', values.username);

    if (this.registerNormal.get('username').valid)
      this.crudService.accountExists(registerNormalFormData).subscribe(result => {console.log(result)});
  }
```

The PHP file works fine since I have tested it with postman and also the `registerNormal()` function works perfectly fine.

I don't seem to pinpoint the issue exactly.

Many thanks!

EDIT:

Below is the html code for the component that calls the function. The function gets called but the result returned by angular is `NULL` however the PHP API returns the result fine with postman

```
   <input matInput placeholder="User Name" formControlName="username" required (input)="CheckAccountAvailability(registerNormal.value)">
```

EDIT 2:

Below is the php code for existingAccounts.php

```
<?php
if ($_GET) 
{
    // include database connection
    include 'config/database.php';

    try
    {        
        // check if account exists in database
        $q_normalAccountExists = "SELECT * FROM normal_accounts WHERE username=:username";
        // $q_bandAccountExists = "SELECT * FROM band_accounts WHERE username=:username";

        // prepare queries to check if accounts exist in database
        $checkNormalAccount = $con->prepare($q_normalAccountExists);
        // $checkBandAccount = $con->prepare($q_bandAccountExists);

        // GET username
        $username = $_GET['username'];

        // bind parameters to check if username exists in database
        $checkNormalAccount->bindParam(':username', $username);
        // $checkBandAccount->bindParam(':username', $username);

        // execute username exists in database query
        $checkNormalAccount->execute();
        // $checkBandAccount->execute();

        if ($checkNormalAccount->rowCount() == 0/* && $checkBandAccount->rowCount() == 0*/)
        {
            echo json_encode(array('result'=>false));
        }

        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array('result'=>true));
        }
    }

    // show error
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT 3:

It seems that changing the GET request to a POST request sorted the issue. However, could anyone tell me why GET requests won't work?

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: @gladiatoriitoo, I have updated my post with the php code. When I log the result to the console, it prints out as NULL instead of true or false.

Comment: `(input)` ?? You want to use `(keydown)` or `(keyup)`. Calling server side to database on every key stroke is a bad idea, consider using debounce.

Comment: @TudorAnghelina, regarding on why GET doesn't work: `A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics`

Comment: i think you should call your api using query string parameters in your GET request from angular